# How do I run NUnit tests on TFS?

Tags: tfs, nunit

**Question:**

How do I run *NUnit* tests on TFS?

**Attempts:**

I've searched the web and am still struggling to figure out the exact steps required to accomplish (to what I believe is) a trivial task.

I added the NUnit3TestAdapter package to my test project.

However, my tests are still not being discovered.

**TFS displays the following message:**

> No test runs are available for this build. Enable automated tests in
>   your build pipeline by running your test framework of choice, such as
>   JUnit, Visual Studio Test, or xUnit. If you choose to run tests using
>   a custom task or runner, you can publish results using the Publish
>   Test Results task.

**Expectation:**

I'm surprised that NUnit is not an option that I can just select from.Hence, it's the standard unit test framework for .Net.

Comment: Can you share your vs test task?

Comment: Can you also share the build logs for test task?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I run NUnit tests on TFS?

There is a blog here describes clearly how to run NUnit tests on TFS: [Running NUnit Tests in a TFS 2015 Build vNext](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2015/03/16/running-nunit-tests-in-a-tfs-2015-build-vnext/)

> Simply summarized as follows:
>
> 1. Add Nuget Package for NUnit Test Adapter
> 2. Specify path of custom Test Adapter inside build definition
>
>    - Copying adapters inside Visual Studio TestWindows folder
>    - Specify Path to Custom Test Adapter with nunit packages
>
> **Note**：
>
> You do need to edit the `Visual Studio Test` task’s advanced settings
>   to point at the NuGet packages folder for your solution (which will be
>   populated via NuGet restore) so the custom nUnit test adaptor can be
>   found i.e. usually setting it to  `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\packages`

Some other tutorial for you reference:

[xUnit or NUnit with Visual Studio Online Build](http://nocture.dk/2015/06/19/xunit-or-nunit-with-visual-studio-online-build/)

[Running nUnit and Jasmine.JS unit tests in TFS/VSO vNext build](https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/rfennell/2015/09/23/running-nunit-and-jasmine-js-unit-tests-in-tfsvso-vnext-build/)